# send html emails using a view as the content

Tags: php

In my base controller I have this code which checks if there is a view and then displays it. I want to modify this to use for sending an email. I basically want to create views which contain html content for sending the mails. But trying to access it normally as if I were displaying a view doesn't quite work. This is the code for displaying the views on the website.

```
public function view($view, $data = []) {
    // check for view file
    if(file_exists('../app/views/' . $view . '.php')) {
        require_once '../app/views/' . $view . '.php';
    } else {
        die('View does not exist');
    }
}
```

To display a view, I would just do this in my controller:

```
$this->view('pages/contact-us');
```

When I am trying to send email, I want to just send the view into the email body.

```
$html = $this->view('pages/email');
//other variables go here

$send = new Email();
$send->sendMail($html, $subject, $setFrom, $addReplyTo, $addAddress, $altBody);
```

Doing this fails. I think I need to just return the view but not sure how to do this.

If I try this:

```
$html = $this->view('pages/contact-email');
```

I get this error:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Exception: <strong>Message body empty</strong><br />

**UPDATE:**

I added this to the controller class:

```
public function getView($view, $data = []) {
if(file_exists('../app/views/' . $view . '.php')) {
     return file_get_contents('../app/views/' . $view . '.php');
} else {
    die('View does not exist');
}
```

}

And then did this in the controller:

```
$html = $this->getView('pages/contact-email', $data);
```

The plain html content is displaying but not the php. If I try this in the view:

```
<?php echo $data['name']; ?>
```

nothing shows up...

Comment: What fails? Have you verified that the issue is not from the `sendMail` function?

Comment: Yes, if I just make $html equal a string then the mail sends just fine.

Comment: @Akintunde007, I updated my question to show the error message

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to add return in your view function.
Because actually your $html is empty.

To return the content of your file, you need to read the file before, for exeample : file_get_contents(PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE),  and after that return the content inside a variable.

Comment: thanks. That almost works perfectly except no dynamic values come through, only plain html. I have updated the question.